What's the naming convention of in-kernel helpers for syscall?
I found out that one of the reasons for changing _do_fork() to kernel_clone() in the Linux kernel is to follow "the naming convention of in-kernel helpers for syscall". I found that in this commit message
I would like to know what is the naming convention of the kernel source code? Does it have to start with kernel_*? But I've seen some kernel functions that don't start with that either.

what is the naming convention of the kernel source code? Are you asking about the convention of the whole source code or just in-kernel syscall helpers?

Many of the syscall helpers (especially the file operation related ones) use the ksys_ prefix. A lot of kernel code used to call the syscall entry points such as sys_read directly, but now they call the ksys_ functions instead.

First of all, I would like to know if there is some commonality in functions that start with kernel_*, for example kernel_clone, kernel_execve, kernel_accept, kernel_fpu_begin they are all kernel functions, but not all kernel functions start with kernel, and I would like to know How to distinguish them. Secondly, I would like to know some more detailed naming rules by which I can understand the feature of the function or variable in kernel source.
